# How to rename multiple folders to new names in a text file

Tags: perl

I have a main folder. And there are 120 subfolders in this main folder.

Their names are as the following:

```
12sg
45gh
46ght
49hk5
.
.
.
zadg54
```

And I have a new name for each subfolders in mol.txt file. There are 120 names in mol.txt

mol.txt file:

```
methyl
ethyl-2
nitro1
pernyty
.
.
.
dpcopt3
```

I want to rename all subfolders to new names in mol.txt file using perl but I don't know how to do it (Directory list is alphabetically. I want to rename them according to this order). Can you help me?

For example:

```
"methyl" name is for 12sg folder
"ethyl-2" name is for 45gh folder
```

Comment: How do you know which names goes with which directory?

Comment: In mol.txt each name is for a folder, respectively.

Comment: How do you know that `12sh` should be renamed to `methyl` for example? That's not in your `mol.txt`.

Comment: `methyl` is in `mol.txt`. It must be new name of `12sg` folder.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Stack Overflow is not a "write my code for me" service.

Comment: @perlselami We have now asked you two times how to match a directory to a name from the mol.txt file. You have both times answered that the names are in the file. We already know this, you mentioned it in the question, and it is because of it that we are asking. Repeating it does not help. You say that `methyl` should be the name for `12sg`, but how does Perl find that out? Where is it written?

Comment: Because `methyl` is the first line in `mol.txt`. And `12sg` is first folder according to alphabetical order of folders. In mol.txt each line represents a folder name ordered alphabetically. if I have 3 folders (e.g: their names are `1,2 and 3`) ,and there are `a,b,and c` names in `mol.txt`, respectively. Then `1`'s new name must be `a`, `2`'s new name must be `b`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first pass is to 'map' your 'old' name to your 'new' name.

How do you know that `12sh` should be renamed to `methyl` for example? That's not in your `mol.txt`.

Anyway, first step is to construct a hash with the relationships. IF you're sure the ordering in your directory matches `mol.txt`. (And be careful with this, there's several possible directory orders, so it's not that safe an assumption) you might:

```
open ( my $input, "<", "mol.txt" );   
opendir ( my $dir_handle, "/your_directory" ); 

#sort because otherwise it's 'filesystem ordered' which may not be alphabetical. 
my @list_of_stuff = sort ( readdir ( $dir_handle ) ); 

foreach my $dirname ( @list_of_stuff )  {
    my $rename_to = <$input>;
    chomp ( $rename_to );

    print "Rename $dirname to $rename_to\n"; 
}
```

If that looks like it produces the right output, then you'd add in the perl [`rename`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html). But please note - there'll be no sorting happening on the directory list here, so ordering may not be what you expect. (Hence why the snippet above doesn't include a `rename`).

Comment: Directory list is alphabetically. I want to rename them according to this order.

Comment: OK. Tweaked the above a little - you'll need a `sort` in there.

Comment: Error:Use of uninitialized value $rename_to in scalar chomp at ./rename.pl line 14, <$input> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value $rename_to in concatenation (.) or string at ./rename.pl line 16, <$input> line 6.
Rename 5 to

Comment: And I think this code wont rename alphabetically. Because I tried it. 1,2,3,4,5 are folder names. a,b,c,d and e are new names in mol.txt. When the code runs, it gives:
Rename . to a
Rename .. to b
Rename 1 to c
Rename 2 to d
Rename 3 to e
Rename 4 to

Comment: OK. you'll need to skip files called '..' and '.

Comment: Thanks. How will I do it?

Comment: `next if $dirname =~ m/^\.\.?$/;`

Comment: It still doesn't work. Screen output:`Rename 1 to a
Rename 2 to b
Rename 3 to c
Rename 4 to d
Rename 5 to e
Rename mol.txt to 
Use of uninitialized value $rename_to in scalar chomp at ./rename.pl line 16, <$input> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value $rename_to in concatenation (.) or string at ./rename.pl line 18, <$input> line 6.
Rename rename.pl to `